# Avoid passing null as the view root (when inflating layout in AlertDialog)

Tags: android

```
public void aboutDialog() {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflaterAndroid = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
        View mView = layoutInflaterAndroid.inflate(R.layout.custom_dialog_about, null);

        final AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        alert.setView(mView);
        alert.setCancelable(false);
        alert.setPositiveButton(R.string.dialog_ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        alert.show();
  }
```

I'm getting this error:

> Avoid passing null as the view root (need to resolve layout parameters
>   on the inflated layout's root element).

This affects my `aboutdialog()` and crashes my application on calling this dialog. 
Please help!

Comment: That message is just a warning. Something else is causing your application to crash; look in the logcat for the stacktrace. Maybe `getActivity()` is returning `null`.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use `alert.setView(R.layout.custom_dialog);` without inflating views.

But in your code try

```
View mView =  View.inflate(getAcctivity(),R.layout.custom_dialog_about,null);
```

this method works when root view is null.

or you can use

```
layoutInflaterAndroid.inflate(R.layout.custom_dialog_about, null , false);
```